# Pubnub - removing a message in history (storage)

Tags: history, pubnub

I'm working in a instant messaging using pubnub as backend on iOS. After some googling, I found this way but for scala.

http://scalabl3.github.io/pubnub-design-patterns/2015/02/26/Message-Update-Delete.html

I wonder if there is a exist way in API to archive this?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to *archive*?

Comment: The example code is in javascript, not scala, but more importantly the ideas behind the post is the Design Pattern, not how messages are published (which is the Javascript). You can publish in any language.

Comment: @CraigConover: I want to remove the message in Storage & Playback.

Comment: @scalabl3: my fault. I jut wonder if they implemented the overwrite history since then.

Comment: Does PubNub charges for persisting history messages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PubNub allows delete messages from the channel

eg:

```
let startDate = NSNumber(value: (15101397027611671 as CUnsignedLongLong))
let endDate = NSNumber(value: (15101397427611671 as CUnsignedLongLong))
self.client.deleteMessage().channel("channel").start( startDate ).end(
endDate).performWithCompletion ( { (status) in

if !status.isError {
    // Messages within specified time frame has been removed.
} else {
   /**
    * Handle message history download error. Check 'category' property to find out possible 
    * issue because of which request did fail.
    *
    * Request can be resent using: status.retry()
    */
}
```

})

Refer [pubnub documentation](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/swift/api-reference-storage-and-playback#delete-messages-from-history) for more details

Answer (score 2):

Pubnub does not currently support deleting things from message history.